# ADF test showing stationary for a non stationary series

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I am running an ADF test in R on the following series:

[image: difference plot time series]

This to me is clearly non-stationary, but when I run the ADF test:

```
library(tseries)
adf.test(spreads[,y]- spreads[,x], alternative="stationary")
```

For whatever lag value I use I get a low p-value indicating a stationary series:

**p-value smaller than printed p-value**

I just can't understand why this is stationary or why the test indicates that it is. I have several examples like this in my data set too.

Comment: The test indicates that the series does not have a unit root. This is not the same as that the series is stationary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a first glance your data seems to be trend stationary. That means that if you subtract the trend (in this case a straight line with positive slope) from the time-series you will have a stationary time series. Trend stationary data is not stationary before you subtract the trend.

---

Also note the official [RDocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tseries/versions/0.10-45/topics/adf.test):

> The general regression equation which incorporates a constant and a linear trend >is used and the t-statistic for a first order autoregressive coefficient equals >one is computed. The number of lags used in the regression is k. The default >value of trunc((length(x)-1)^(1/3)) corresponds to the suggested upper bound on >the rate at which the number of lags, k, should be made to grow with the sample >size for the general ARMA(p,q) setup. Note that for k equals zero the standard >Dickey-Fuller test is computed. The p-values are interpolated from Table 4.2, p. >103 of Banerjee et al. (1993). If the computed statistic is outside the table of >critical values, then a warning message is generated.
>
> Missing values are not allowed

There are some exceptions, e.g. missing values.

---

Furthermore here:

[What is the difference between a stationary test and a unit root test?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/what-is-the-difference-between-a-stationary-test-and-a-unit-root-test/235916#235916)

and here:

[Contradictory results of ADF and KPSS unit root tests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239360/contradictory-results-of-adf-and-kpss-unit-root-tests/239367#239367)

and here:

[ADF test, PP test, KPSS test: Which test to prefer?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88407/adf-test-pp-test-kpss-test-which-test-to-prefer/315138#315138)

I already explained situations, in which the Nullhypothesis of an ADF-test is rejected and a time series is not-stationary. You should apply a KPSS test for stationarity as well.

> Reject unit root, reject stationarity: both hypothesis are component hypothesis >– heteroskedasticity in series may make a big difference; if there is structural >break it will affect inference.

Comment: Thank you this really helped, sorry it has been asked so many times, I didn't really know what to look for however. My KPSS test has a p values < 0.01, I think as the null hypothesis is the opposite of the ADF test I can reject the null hypothesis of trend stationary right? I'm simply trying to find co-integration between two time series and the plot is the difference between the two which are definitely not co-integrated.

Comment: For Cointegration it is better to look for specialized cointegration tests, e.g. Johansen Test.

Comment: Thanks @Ferdi will have a look! I tried the engle granger test but was running into problems with the apparent time series' being stationary which perhaps they were just trend stationary. Is there a reason why the Johansen Test is preferable?

Comment: I think both tests are suitable https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96789/whats-the-practical-difference-between-the-johansen-vs-engle-granger-tests-for

Comment: Just a small question about the Johansen test when only using two variables I’m a bit confused when I reject r0 but can’t reject r<=1

Comment: Thanks for the help, I now understand a lot more and I am using a slightly different package in r that does ADF with the three different regression equations, I specifically want constant but no linear trend, whereas the tseries adf function as you mentioned uses both.