# determine if series is non-stationary or stationery

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller, kpss-test

I have series and I need to determine if the series is stationary or non-stationary. According to this web page [Link](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/stationarity_detrending_adf_kpss.html), is prefer to use the ADF and KPSS and then judge on the series. My result of ADF saying it is stationary and the result of KPSS saying it is non-stationary. So, I have the case 4 " KPSS indicates non-stationarity and ADF indicates stationarity - The series is difference stationary. Differencing is to be used to make series stationary. The differenced series is checked for stationarity." In fact, I could not understand that meaning, now is my series is stationary or non-stationary?

Comment: This might be helpful https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372145/adf-test-showing-stationary-for-a-non-stationary-series

Comment: I'm still confuse in case 4 :(