# Can I use Engle-Granger test on cointegration of multivariate time series

Tags: time-series, cointegration

As I understand, the VECM and Johansen test should be used when there could be multiple cointegration relation.The EG test works when only one co-integration relation exist.

In Engle-Granger 1987 paper, all examples are bivariate. In the "Econometric Analysis 7th Edition", only the Johansen method is apply to the example with multivariate series in the co-integration section 21.3.5. In the "Analysis of Integrated and Cointegrated Time Series with R", EG method is shown in bivariate example. The only example I found where EG test applied to multivariate case is in the paper "Stationary and cointegration tests:Comparison of Engle - Granger and Johansen methodologies".

Although the textbooks or papers doesn't explicitly says that EG should only be used on bivariate case and Johansen test should be used on multivariate case, I was wondering if this is a rule, and what the results would be if I do otherwise.

My questions are

1. Can I use the EG test on multivariate time series?
2. What is the consequence to use EG test when there is actually more than one co-integration vectors?
3. Do I still use the static regression in EG method to evaluate the long-run relationship?

A relevant post focuses on bivariate case

[What's the practical difference between the Johansen vs Engle-Granger tests for cointegration?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96789/whats-the-practical-difference-between-the-johansen-vs-engle-granger-tests-for)

Any comments would be appreciated.